# Update SQLite query with IN keyword

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this function for Update Query.

```
public long updateUsePin(String usePinId){
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(PIN_USEDSTATUS, 1);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_UPDATED_AT, dateFormat.format(date));
    return ispDatabase.update(PIN_UPDATED_AT, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + " IN " + usePinId, null);

}
```

When I run this, this is crash. This query style not working what I needed. I want to use like that

```
 UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET(COL = value) WHERE ID IN (1,2,4);
```

How can I do that? Please pointing to me. Thanks with advanced!

Comment: Please share the format your `usePinId` has.

Comment: ispDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET(COL = value) WHERE ID IN (1,2,4)");

Comment: usePinId is (1,2,3,4)

Comment: ispDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET(COL = value) WHERE ID IN " + usePinId);

Comment: Please share the output of logcat. It should show exactly where the problem is in the query. I'm just guessing here, but are you sure PIN_UPDATED_AT holds the name of the table you want to update?

Comment: Sorry all. That's my fault! Actually, PIN_UPDATED_AT is not table name. So, I will change PIN_UPDATED_AT to DATABASE_TABLE_PIN. It's OK now. Thanks for helpful flag and comment.